# How to delete many rows typeorm - postgresql & node.js(typescript)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Hi friends this is my function, it gets an array of ids I want to erase the rows in one stroke and not run in the loop, and can't find a solution to that.
Would appreciate help.

```
async remove(ids: DeleteEmployeeAnswerDTO): Promise<boolean> {
        if (ids.employeeAnswersIds.length) {
            for (const id of ids.employeeAnswersIds) {
                await EmployeeAnswers.delete(id.id);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This is what worked for me https://medium.com/@jimkang/typeorm-delete-multiple-records-6119ff8b740

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

If your table has a single `ID` column then you should be able to pass an array of `ID`s:

```
await EmployeeAnswers.delete(ids.employeeAnswersIds);
```

You could also specify multiple `ID`s in your where clause using `In`:

```
await EmployeeAnswers.delete({ id: In(ids.employeeAnswersIds) });
```

However if you deal with a table that has a composite primary key, like in my case, the following example can be the solution for you. I'm not crazy about this answer, but here is how I overcame this problem using `DeleteQueryBuilder` ([docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/delete-query-builder.md)):

```
async remove(ids: DeleteEmployeeAnswerDTO): Promise<boolean> {
  if (ids.employeeAnswersIds.length) {
    const deleteQueryBuilder = EmployeeAnswer.createQueryBuilder().delete()

    const idClauses = ids.map((_, index) => `ID = :id${index}`)
    const idClauseVariables = ids.reduce((value: any, id, index) => {
      value[`id${index}`] = id
      return value
    }, {})

    await deleteQueryBuilder.where(idClauses.join(' OR '), idClauseVariables).execute()
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Since the example provided by the questioner made it clear, that his entity has only one primary key, I would highlight the last example you provided.

Comment: the In(taskIds) does not work in my case and it gives sql error, Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause

Answer (score 1):

You can search for multiple records and then delete the entities found in a single operation. If one or more entities are not found, then nothing is deleted.

```
async removeMany(ids: string[]) {
    const entities = await this.entityRepository.findByIds(ids);
    if (!entities) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`Some Entities not found, no changes applied!`);
    }
    return this.entityRepository.remove(entities);
  }
```

Comment: This can work, however the process contains an unnecessary query. If there are a tons of ids, the first query can be very slow.

Comment: Yes but in my experience remove or delete fails catastrophically if the provided id doesn't exist in the table. Server just crashes... it's insane if you ask me. How would you circumvent this problem in a single query? Regards

Comment: Supposedly findByIds is deprecated. There is a note that says to use findBy in conjunction with the `In` operator. But I failed to make it work so far.

Comment: In my case, I had done the query before already, so the remove function worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had the same issue.
My case could help if you use NestJS + typeorm.

Here is a module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { TaskController } from './task.controller';
import { Task } from './task.entity';
import { TaskService } from './task.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Task])],
  controllers: [TaskController],
  providers: [TaskService],
  exports: [TaskService],
})
export class TaskModule {}
```

Here is a part of my controller:

```
import { Controller, Delete, Query, Request } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TaskService } from './task.service';


@Controller('task')
export class TaskController {
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  @Delete('/multiple/')
  async deleteMultiple(@Request() req, @Query('ids') ids: string[]) {
    const userId = req.user.id;

    try {
      await this.taskService.deleteMultiple(userId, ids);

      return 'success';
    } catch (error) {
      return 'error';
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { In, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Task) private repo: Repository<Task>) {}

  async deleteMultiple(userId: string, taskIds: string[]) {
    return await this.repo.delete({ userId, id: In(taskIds) });
  }
}
```

So, the solution is **In(taskIds)**

I hope it could be useful for someone.

Comment: the `In(taskIds)` does not work in my case and it gives sql error, Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that using this:

```
const items = req.body.linesIds.map((id) => ({ id, companyId: req.$USER?.companyId }))
// @ts-expect-error
const dbRes = await Line.delete(items)
```

This sends a single query, and even though it gives a type error, but it works perfectly fine, I believe this is something to change in the TypeORM type detention

Answer (score -3):

Use the "clear" method to clear all data recorded in the table!

```js
async deleteProducts() {
  await this.productRepository.clear();
  return {
    message: MESSAGE.PRODUCTS_REMOVED
  };
}
```

Comment: Supposedly clear is deprecated